# REACT-SELECT Color the background of my cell if a choice is selected (or just the text itself)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I want to fill the background of my dropbox cell if a selection is made. For example Taste:`Good`, and the Comments: `3/4`, which must be the defaut value from the match.json. The background of the cell should be in green if it's `Good` . And the `3/4` cell should be in yellow. (cf image)

For Availability, it will be only checkbox that is already in blue if availability is 1 else not fill in blue.

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
```

Display:

```
export default function Display() {
 ...
  const styles = {
    select: {
      width: "100%",
      maxWidth: 150
    }
  };
  const TASTE = [
    { label: "Good", value: "Good" },
    { label: "Medium", value: "Medium" },
    { label: "Bad", value: "Bad" }
  ];
...   

  return (
    <>
        <div className="TextStyle">
          {"Taste "}
          <CustomDropdown
            style={styles.select}
            options={TASTE}
            defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === 
              item.taste)}
          />
        </div>
        ...
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what the current output looks like, and a mockup of what you are trying to get the result to be?

Comment: Based on your screenshot it appears your question is (*quite*) a bit more than just rendering and styling the specific item fields/properties. Can you try getting the existing `div` elements and plain text closer to what you are going for? Either using a `select` element or a dropdown component or similar? Where do these options come from? What to do with the selections? We can help you with existing code, and we can help fill in gaps, but SO isn't really for complete code generation.

Comment: Yeah ofc I already have the dropdown in my code. But how can I fill it in different color?

Comment: Yeah, I also saw that and noticed that it also doesn't appear to take any props to set initial/default/controlled values, all its state is internal it seems.

Comment: Do you think it's my Dropdown.jsx file that I should modifie or maybe using css can help me?

Comment: Oh, if you want to use the same `Dropdown` component it'll need to be updated a bit, CSS alone won't address converting it to allow some external control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Select component you can use a prop called **styles** where you can actually create a logic for displaying a different color based on the selection you made. For example: if you want to have the background color green only when you select Good then you can create an object like this:

```
const colourStyles = {
  singleValue: (provided, { data }) => ({
    ...provided,
    backgroundColor: data.value === "Good" ? "green" : "",
  }),
};
```

And then pass the object **colourStyles** to the CustomDropDown as prop:

```
<CustomDropdown
 style={styles.select}
 options={TASTE}
 defaultValue={TASTE.find(t => t.label === item.taste)}
 styleSelect={colourStyles}
/>
```

Finally inside the CustomDropdown component pass the **styleSelect** to the Select component like this (remember to add the new prop I've created as an argument inside the CustomDropdown component):

```
<Select 
 options={options} 
 defaultValue={defaultValue}
 styles={styleSelect}
/>
```

You can then do the same for the other CustomDropDown component.