# REACT-SELECT defaultValue in CustomDropdown not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-select

I want the default value of my dropdown to be `defaultValue={item.taste}` (value from `match.json`) but it's not working... (go to /menu/Menu1 and Pea Soup)

```
import Select from "react-select";

export default function CustomDropdown({ style, options, defaultValue }) {
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <Select options={options} defaultValue={defaultValue} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

MenuItemDisplay:

```
export default function MenuItemDisplay() {

  const { menuId, itemId } = useParams();
  const { match } = JsonData;    
  const matchData = match.find((el) => el._id_menu === menuId)?._ids ?? [];
  const item = matchData.find((el) => el._id === itemId);

  const styles = {
    select: {
      width: "100%",
      maxWidth: 150
    }
  };
  const TASTE = [
    { label: "Good", value: "Good" },
    { label: "Medium", value: "Medium" },
    { label: "Bad", value: "Bad" }
  ];
...   

  return (
    <>
        <div className="TextStyle">
          {"Taste "}
          <CustomDropdown
            style={styles.select}
            options={TASTE}
            defaultValue={item.taste}
           //The default value is not working only if it's 
           //TASTE[0]
          />
        </div>
        ...
    </>
  );
}
```

Here the link for the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-z37eu1?file=/src/MenuItemDisplay.jsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defaultValue you need to pass one of the objects of the **TASTE** array. You can do this:

```
<CustomDropdown
  style={styles.select}
  options={TASTE}
  defaultValue={TASTE.find(t => t.label === item.taste)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks man! Btw do you know how we can add color to the label : "Good" is displayed in green for instance [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864335/react-select-color-the-background-of-my-cell-if-a-choice-is-selected-or-just-th?noredirect=1#comment127030791_71864335) ?

Comment: Yes. I've answered you in the other post ;)